# Defining a defualt value for my javascript function parameter will raise the following error on IE " SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the followig function inside my javascript file:-

```
function showOrHideField(curField="") {
```

where i am defining a function which take a parameter with defualt value `""`, now this is working well on Firefox. but on IE11 i got the following exception:-

```
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
```

so can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Comment: because IE11 does not support that feature https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 does not support [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility)

```
function showOrHideField(curField="") {
```

would need to be

```
function showOrHideField(curField) {
   curField = curField || "";
   //or
   curField = curField!==undefined ? curField : "";
```

Comment: great ..........

Comment: Or use a buildscript that runs a transpilier allows you to use those features and fixes the code  for you. ;) https://babeljs.io/